# how to make the BottomBar fixed in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomnav

[this is my bottom bar and i want to make it fixed without this animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XERPS.png)

my navigation code

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    app:tabMode="fixed"


    android:backgroundTint="#F0F0F0"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"

    />
```

Comment: You can try using `TabLayout` and place it at bottom. It would work same.

Answer (score 0):

The menu icon shifts a bit when selected. The most easiest way to solve this would be to use the [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) library.

[image]